# Can I send push notification without using device token

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send automatic push notifications to my clients who are installing my flutter application. Can I do it without getting their device tokens. I am using firestore as my database

Answer (score 5):

You can send messages to client apps using [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), but each client app will need to be subscribed to the named topic.  You will not be able to single out a specific device without a device token.